# How to match the titles of a person using regular expressions

Tags: r, grepl

By using regular expressions to match the title. Write R snippet that creates a new column called “Female” and fills it with TRUE/FALSE values based on the text provided in the “Name” column. Like if it is "Miss" TRUE, if no salutation assign as "NA"

This is the data frame

```
df <- data.frame(PersonID=1:8, Name=c("Mr. Bob", "Ms. Blank", "Roger, Mr.", "MR Mark Simpson", "Miss Lisa", "Mrs. joshep", "Rakesh Kumar", "Kumar Gums Murphy"))

grepl("Miss", df, perl=TRUE)
```

output:

```
FALSE,FALSE,FALSE
```

expected output:

```
FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,NA,NA
```

Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: You need to etract the column 'Name' ie. `grepl("Miss", df$Name, perl = TRUE)`

Comment: But i need to get  NA if neither male nor female?How could i get this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `NA` for non-specified you have to first rule out that other designations are not present. That is, just because `"Miss"` is not present doesn't mean `"Mr"` or `"MISS"` are not.

The following will assign `"M"`,`"F"` or `NA` in your example. Please add designation as needed.

```
Titles <- c("Miss", "Ms","Mr","Mrs","MR","MS","MRS","MISS") # vector of possible titles
f.Titles <- c("Miss", "Ms","Mrs","MS","MRS","MISS") # vector of female specific titles
check <- NULL
for(i in 1:length(Titles)){
  check <- cbind(check,grepl(Titles[i], df$Name, perl=TRUE))
}

colnames(check) <- Titles
apply(check,1,function(x)ifelse(!any(x),NA,
                                ifelse(any(names(which(x)) %in% f.Titles),"F","M")))
```

Output :

```
[1] "M" "F" "M" "M" "F" "F" NA  NA
```

From there its a simple

```
G <- apply(check,1,function(x)ifelse(!any(x),NA,
                                     ifelse(any(names(which(x)) %in% f.Titles),"F","M")))

df$Female <- ifelse(G=="F",TRUE,ifelse(is.na(G),NA,FALSE))
df
  PersonID              Name Female
1        1           Mr. Bob  FALSE
2        2         Ms. Blank   TRUE
3        3        Roger, Mr.  FALSE
4        4   MR Mark Simpson  FALSE
5        5         Miss Lisa   TRUE
6        6       Mrs. joshep   TRUE
7        7      Rakesh Kumar     NA
8        8 Kumar Gums Murphy     NA
```

### Edit 1 :

Here is a more efficient version that does exactly what you asked for. Still need to specify all possible `Titles` and female titles (`f.Titles`)

```
check <- apply(as.matrix(Titles), 1, function(x) grepl(x, df$Name, perl=TRUE))
colnames(check) <- Titles
df$Female <- apply(check,1,function(x)ifelse(!any(x),NA,ifelse(any(names(which(x)) %in% f.Titles),TRUE,FALSE)))
```

Comment: Code was bugged and not correctly identifying Females. This is now fixed.